# groovy how to get next month from given date

Tags: date, groovy

Hi can anybody please help me in this. I want to display all the months from a given specific date.

for Eg: given date is: 15-Mar-2011
Output should be: Mar/2011,Apr/2011 .... Feb/2012

How can i acheive the above in groovy?

Comment: display all months until? feb 2012?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Groovy's TimeCategory to write sth. like `myDate + 3.months`. The following code creates the list you wanted:

```
use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    Date date = Date.parse("dd-MMM-yyyy", "15-Mar-2011")

    def months = (0..11).collect { 
        (date + it.months).format("MMM/yyyy") 
    }
}
```